# _id from prop showing up as undefined (React)

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, state, mern

I am creating a MERN app (with React Redux) and I am sending the workout info (_id, workout_name, etc) from Program.js into the Workout.js by a prop. However, in my Workout.js, workout._id keeps showing up as undefined when I use it in my axios post method within Workout.js to create a new exercise.

```
POST http://localhost:5000/exercise/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

POST http://localhost:5000/exercise/[workoutId] (how its supposed to be)
```

or like:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Workout"
```

If I try displaying the workout._id in the console, it will show up though, so i dont know what the issue is.

**Program.js**

```
function Program({program : {program_name, workouts}}) {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container border-2 p-3 rounded-lg mb-3 bg-slate-100'>
                <div className='font-bold text-2xl text-black pl-5 pb-3'>{program_name}</div>
                {workouts.map((workout) => (
                    <Workouts key={workout._id} workout={workout}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Program
```

here is the Workout.js:

**Workout.js**

```
  function Workouts({ workout: { workout_name, exercises, _id }}) {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)

  const [exerciseData, setExerciseData] = useState({
    exercise_name:"",
    notes:""
  })

  const changeMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const id = _id.toString()
    console.log(exerciseData)
    console.log(id)
    dispatch(createExercise(exerciseData, id)) // exercise _id
    clear()
  }

  const clear = () => {
    setExerciseData({
      exercise_name:"",
      notes:""
    })
  }

  exercises.forEach(e => console.log(e._id, e.exercise_name)) // exercise._ids show up no prob
  console.log(_id) // id shows up just fine here!!
  
  return (
    <div className='border-2 p-1 rounded-md bg-white mb-2'>
        <div className='font-bold text-lg text-black pl-4 pb-1'>{workout_name}</div>
        {exercises.map((exercise) => (
            (<Exercises key={exercise._id} exercise={exercise}/>)
        ))}
        <div className='flex justify-center p-1'>
          <button onClick={changeMenu} className='btn font-bold text-sm text-slate-600 bg-white border-gray-500 border-2 hover:bg-fitprimary hover:text-white'><BsFillPlusCircleFill className='mr-2'/>Add Exercise</button>
        </div>
        {menuOpen &&
          (
            <div>
            <div className='flex justify-center'>
              <input value={exerciseData.exercise_name} onChange={(e) => setExerciseData({...exerciseData, exercise_name: e.target.value})} type="text" placeholder="exercise name" className='input w-sm border-slate-500 border-2 m-3 text-center bg-white'></input>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-center mb-3'>
              <button onClick={handleSubmit} className='btn btn-sm btn-ghost hover:bg-success hover:text-white'>Confirm</button>
            </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Workouts
```

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Here is the full error if necessary:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Workout"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4678:21)      
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4777:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"undefined"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'undefined',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:65:23)
      at castObjectId (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:24:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:247:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1182:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1616:15)
5)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1583:20)
      at cast (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:344:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\DATA\Max\Desktop\FitNote-Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5113:12),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Comment: what do you get in the `handleSubmit()` `console.log(id)`? Please provide the ID if it's not a security risk.

Comment: i get '6254c6f0ba5ffdbf2a6a4db2' printing out, which is the workout._id but then when it actually dispatches, it sends the error above

Comment: I think the issue might have something to do with axios. I tried flipping the data and the id in the request

Comment: export const createSet = (exerciseId, data) => axios.post(`${url}/${exerciseId}`, data)

Comment: and now the request is going through but the data is empty! so the second parameter is becoming undefined for some reason

Comment: Could you show us your createExercise in the reducer?

Comment: I think it has something to do with converting your id to an objectid which is what mongodb uses for _Id

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you regardless. I forgot to add the second parameter in my action file. so axios was using just the data but not the id